# How I could make a bus connection in a prototype shield?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, shields

I am a programmer but pretty new to electronics , I recently bought a prototyping shield like the picture :
[image]

In my view there is no bus connections here . I have lots components need connect to solder into a single board , and some ports like GND and VCC , SDA and SCL need connect via buses , how could I make solder such a bus connection by using this shield?

Should I just continuously solder through the holes I want to form a bus?

Thanks..!

Comment: If the board has copper on both sides you can solder a copper wire on the bottom to create a "bus".

Comment: Sounds reasonable ,however I don't have copper currently , can I just use the solder?

Comment: You can, but solder doesn't really want to stick to the solder-mask between the pads. You can just strip some electrical cable, speaker cable, whatever you have laying around.

Comment: Thanks Gerben , so should I put copper wire straight on the back face of the board and cover holes , then I soldering other wires in the front face ? or should I soldering wires first , and use a copper attach them and solder together both in front face ?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. Whatever works for you. I never liked protoboard. So went almost straight to developing my own circuit-boards.

Answer (score 1):

I would mount the components to the board first then create busses with wire. Depending on the components you might be able to use the same row the component leads are in or you may need to lay the bus in the adjacent row and bridge the gap with component leads.

A quick search turned up an image that sort of gives an idea of what I'm talking about. If you look closely you can see the wire bridging the gap between each solder pad.

https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=soldering+protoboard+bus+wiring&view=detailv2&&&id=EF1514CA6486FC44E0132E7DE1CFBFDBFD015809&selectedIndex=15&ccid=vQ%2beHllm&simid=608022938507020230&thid=JN.TBpqHtXSA7o3dTvD8dPVaQ&ajaxhist=0